# Executing multiple activities in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I was trying to execute one activity after executing another,by using threads and using sleep method of thread class.
Here is the code,

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layo);
        Thread th=new Thread() {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {

                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException i)
                {
                    i.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent io=new Intent("com.example.admin.myapplication.NEWATTEMPT");
                    startActivity(io);
                }
            }

        };
        th.start();

    }
```

> Code for layo.xml is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pic">

</LinearLayout>
```

and NewAttempt is another java class-

My question here is this-
In line no. 16 of MainActivity,I am setting the content to layo.xml,and after that I am creating an instance of thread class and starting it,
but,If I put setContentView(R.layout.layo) in the try block,then its showing an error,on starting the application.Why is it so??Can somebody explain why?

And can somebody please explain how an execution happens in android,i.e,order in which files are read?I am a beginner in Android and I doesn't have much idea how the control flows from one activity to another?

Comment: If you do that(have setContentView in try block )Your try is inside a Thread. You need to do that on the ui thread. There is a manifest file where you declare activities. Android parses that xml and looks for a launcher activity to launch your first activity. Read the docs for more info on this. http://developer.android.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to modify your view inside Activity, you need to do it on your activity(ui) thread. UI thread is synchronized. Activity has a method that can handle your Runnable

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your method that modify view
        }
    });
```

In your case, you can put method above inside your thread

```
    Thread th = new Thread() {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                      //your method that modify view
                      MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.layo);
                   }
                });
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException i)
            {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                Intent io = new Intent("com.example.admin.myapplication.NEWATTEMPT");
                startActivity(io);
            }
        }

    };
    th.start();
```

Comment: Anyway, i think you don't need to setContentView() inside your th thread. Tell me why do you need that? If it is only for testing then it's ok then.

Comment: -It's only for testing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a splash screen model activities, then try timer() class and schedule it.
try this code inside onCreate() method
eg:

```
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NEWATTEMPT.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    },1000);
```